# Shape keys not deforming correctly

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I was using the shape keys but they are not deforming correctly.

I don't know how to explain this further, I'll show the pics

Eyebrows:

[image: EYEBROWS]

[image: EYEBROWS]

Comment: maybe the best is to share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Of course  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=dso8Ea3J" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/dso8Ea3J/)

Comment: could you please tell more precisely where is the problem? You need to keep in mind that if you put all the values at 1 they will cumulate, maybe this is the problem you're talking about?

Comment: could you explain what cumulate actually means because Im new to Blender actually

Comment: for example if shapekey1 moves a vertex +1 unit on the Z axis and shapekey2 moves the same vertex +1 unit on the Z axis as well, if you set both shapekey1 and shapekey2 value at 1, the vertex will move up by 2 units (1+1), not just 1 unit.

Comment: Ok,uhh, lemme just rephrase my question. So when I move the eyebrow in edit mode, it moves as it must be moving. But when I go into the object mode and try moving it, it doesnt move correctly. Is there ACTUALLY a way to fix it.

Comment: it doesn't move it correctly because the same vertices must be moving because of the other shapekeys and it's taken into account as you've left heir value at 1

Comment: Could you please explain in more details.Pics perhaps?Also Happy New Year!

Comment: happy new year to you too  ;)  by the way, I'm not sure shapekeys are the best idea to animate a face, it's a quick solution but it may cause problem, bones are better in long term and for complex animations

Comment: tbh im creating this model to jesu port it into sfm and use it for my own purposes.So I thought using bones would be too cool for me to use at my current level of animation(modelling, actually). And shapekeys,well,they are easier to use + takes less time to learn then bones(in my opinion)

Comment: yes but shapekey can cause this kind of problem, so it is useful to deform a mesh sometimes but for complex face animation it should probably be avoided imho

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is the following one:

Your shapkeys are set to *Relative*. Let's say that you have a cube and that the shapeky #1 will be this one, i.e. vertex going up:

[image]

Now, bring back the shapekey #1 value at 0. Create your second shapekey, let's say that for this shapekey the same vertex goes up:

[image]

Now keep shapekey #2 value at 1, and move shapekey #1 value up to 1 as well, you'll see that vertex 1 will cumulate shapekey #1 and #2 effects:

[image]

I guess this it what happens here, as you've left some shapekeys value at 1, and as you've moved the same vertices in different shapekeys, their movements cumulate.

Maybe disable *Relative* to switch to *Linear* (which allows to go from a pose to another), or use bones instead of shapekeys.